# "They're just off two years puttin' down revolts."

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I am wondering what **off** here means in this line from the movie *The Alamo* and what is this usage. It's a scene of three Texans chatting about the Mexican army marching before them.

> Man A: That's the best-dressed army I ever saw.
>
> Man B: Fancy clothes don't make a fightin' man.
>
> Man C: They're just **off** two years puttin' down revolts. They're fightin' men.

Prepositions are difficult. I have never see **off** used this way. What does it mean here?

Comment: My guess would be: "They're just off (for) two years puttin' down revolts." *off* meaning *away*. Haven't seen the movie though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There **off** means "having come from" or "having finished".

> He's just  off his shift at the coal mine and wants a shower and a hot meal.

Compare these uses of **[off a stint](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22off%20a%20stint%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)**.

P.S. I include "off a stint" because **two years putting down revolts** is a way of referring to a stint of revolt-suppressing. Note the pattern:

*eight hours washing dishes*

*two years experimenting with elastomers*

*all day painting fences*

> He had just come from *eight hours washing dishes* and didn't feel like studying for the final exam.

Comment: Yes, in other words, the Texans are saying the Mexican army isn't a bunch of inexperienced draftees, they've spent the past two years fighting other rebels.